# Determine the truth value of statement

Tags: logic

The statement is :

***If polygon A does not have 3 sides, then polygon A does not have equal sides in length.***

Some people say this statement is true because it must have at least 3 sides to form a polygon.

But some people say it is false because to form an equal length of sides, it is not necessary to have only 3 sides, it can be 4 sides, 5 sides......

So, this statement is true or false? thanks in advanced!

Comment: What about a square?

Comment: "does not have 3 sides" does not exclude 4 or more sides

Comment: The square is a counterexample. It satisfies "A does not have 3 sides" but does not satisfy "A does not have equal side lengths", so the "if ... then ..." statement is false.

Comment: I think this is a simple question of ambiguity of English speech.  It all depend on how you read "does not have $3$ sides".  Do you read it as saying "does not have *at least* $3$ sides" or do you read it as saying "dos not have *exactly* $3$ sides"?  That's not a math question, just a question of language.

Comment: @lulu does a good job of getting to the heart of the problem. The truth value of the statement depends on how the question is interpreted. It should be worded more precisely to avoid ambiguity. It would also be helpful to know if we are talking about a *particular* polygon called $A$ or an $arbitrary$ polygon called $A$ coming from the set of all polygons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument is valid, because we may find polygons whose sides are equal in length with more than three sides. The easiest example turns out to be the square, even if all regular $n$-gons are also valid counter-examples.

The first argument says basically that the statement is a vacuously true implication, but it doesn't work in the present case, because "no 3 sides" is not equivalent to "less than 3 sides".